# creating web application in sharepoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013, web-application, iis7

I have created a web application in sharepoint 2013 using central admin, that is successfully created. its successfully created app pool in IIS as well. In host file I have also added entry like this:

```
127.0.0.1      myapp.intranet.dev
```

but when I browse http://myapp.intranet.dev it gives `404 not found error`
I could not understand where is problem? can somebody guide me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to *Create a Site Collection* in your Web Application. Go to Central Administration and choose **Create Site Collection** in the Application Management group.

[image]

Enter a title in your Site Collection, select template to use and the primary site collection administrator:

[image]

---

This can be done using PowerShell as well. Don't forget to Set Execution Policy and add PSSnapin for Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell. First find out which template you're going to use through this command:

```
>Get-SPWebTemplate
```

Then assign the chosen template to the template variable:

```
>$template = Get-SPWebTemplate "STS#0"
```

Finally create the site collection:

```
>New-SPSite -Url "<URL for the new site collection>" -OwnerAlias "<domain\user>" -Template $template
```

---

Reference [Create a site collection in SharePoint 2013](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263094.aspx)